# Linux kernel - Find current process (task_struct) by pid

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547332/efficient-way-to-find-task-struct-by-pid).

But my question is the CURRENT process, not any process (find using pid). Since I can't find any documentation except from code (i.e: [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0.5/source/kernel/pid.c)) about how to use provided function, expected input, output...

**Edit**: I mean, if I declare task_struct* task, is this mean task pointer has already point to the current process?

Comment: What do you mean by _current_ process?  That's not necessarily a well defined question.  A process can always find its own PID with `getpid()` (or the `$$` variable in shell scripts).  But outside of that "current" is vague.

Comment: @StephenHarris I mean, if I declare task_struct* task, is this mean task pointer has already point to the current process?

Comment: @StephenHarris Also, how do you find any documentation about how to use provided function, expected input, output? For example,  I see get_pid() and pid_task() do the same thing, which make me confuse.

Answer (score -1):

Linux kernel is multitheaded, many processes executing simultaneously. By the time you receive the PID for the current process, it would likely no longer be the 'current' process.

Non-preemptible kernels may run one process to completion, but not usually. You can set the nice level for each process. A nice level of -20 (not very nice) will devote the entire system to that process until it completes, but in an intelligent way.

If the process must perform disk reads, and the syatem is capable of direct reads to memory, them the kernel might permit a few million cpu cycles to another process.

But with a desktop system, there aren't many user processes set to -20 nice level. They're between -10 and 10. If you launch `top` you can view the top processes, and nice level is shown for each one.

Linux is made to work in a UNIX fashion, which uses a multithreaded kernel. Each thread can belong to the same process, or all different ones. Generally, a desktop system needs to be responsive to user interaction, so it uses a preemptible kernel and a fast timer.

Servers many times suffer grave performance degradation unless the kernel is nonpreemptible. The concepts of threading, preemption and locking are quite complex. But this gives a little overview:

[Preemption and threading](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall09/cos318/lectures/ThreadImplementation.pdf)

Comment: Also, how do you find any documentation about how to use provided function, expected input, output? For example,  I see get_pid() and pid_task() do the same thing, which make me confuse.

Comment: @awesome14 code doesn’t execute in a void, there is always a current process, and it doesn’t magically change (from the perspective of a caller retrieving the current pid).

Comment: That's only with kernel processes. Since it wasn't specified, I had to guess he wanted current user process. There is actually always a current user process, but those user processes switch. So, it's not magic, as you seem to imply my explanation to mean.

Comment: @awesome14 whether it’s a user or kernel process doesn’t matter here. There is always a current user process, but when the current process changes, the code running in that process stops running, and only starts running again when that process is current again. So from the perspective of code retrieving the current pid (and any related info), that current pid is always valid because the code only runs when it is the current pid.